# I don't know how to convert my table using pivot function

Tags: sql

I got table 'students' as below:

```
student    |        section
-----------+-----------------
john       |        Ace
jack       |        Newbie
kiya       |        Top
BRET       |        Top
Scott      |        Top
Stephen    |        Ace
Fran       |        Ace
Chris      |        Good
Kathleen   |        Good
Rick       |        Newbie
```

I'm trying to pivot the table but not getting it.

I've searched in Stackoverflow also but I think my desired output is different so I couldn't find appropriate query.

Here is the expected output :

```
Ace      Top      newbie    good
------------------------------------
India    N/A       N/A      N/A
N/A      N/A       jack     N/A
N/A      kiya      N/A      N/A
N/A      BRET      N/A      N/A
N/A      Scott     N/A      N/A
Stephen  N/A       N/A      N/A
Fran     N/A       N/A      N/A
N/A      N/A       N/A      Chris              
N/A      N/A       N/A      Kathleen           
N/A      N/A       Rick     N/A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'Ace' THEN student END) Ace,
    MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'Top' THEN student END) Top,
    MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'Newbie' THEN student END) Newbie,
    MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'Good' THEN student END) Good
FROM students
GROUP BY student
ORDER BY student
```

If you actually want to see `'N/A'` in the resultset when there is no match instead of `NULL` values, then use `COALESCE()` (or the equivalent for your RDBMS):

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'Ace' THEN student END), 'N/A') Ace,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'Top' THEN student END), 'N/A') Top,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'Newbie' THEN student END), 'N/A') Newbie,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'Good' THEN student END), 'N/A') Good
FROM students
GROUP BY student
ORDER BY student
```

Comment: getting Unknown column 'section' in 'field list' when I execute the query.

When i try 'section' , getting table with all N/A instead of student names displaying in respecting columns.

any suggestions ?

Comment: Oh ! I was so dumb to change it as per my column name. Thank you so much guys